# Segmenting returns from .each method rails using children conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a permissions table that belongs to document.rb and document belongs to workstream.rb

```
<% @permissions.each do |p| %>
  <% if current_user.workstream === p.document.workstream %>
     # all the values that are true to this condition should be captured in an array or .where sort of return array           
  <% end  %>
<% end %>
```

please how can I capture the values that are true to the if condition in an array and count the values.

so store all permissions that have the same document in the current users workstream in an array and count

```
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :id, use: :slugged
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :document
 enum status: [:request, :approved, :rejected]
end   

class Document < ApplicationRecord
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :doc_uuid, use: :slugged
 mount_uploader :doc_resource_url, DocumentUploader
 before_save :generate_token
 belongs_to :workstream
 has_one :document_meta
 belongs_to :state
 has_many :permissions
end

class Workstream < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :fullname, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :unit
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :documents
  has_many :user_workstreams
  has_many :users, through: :user_workstreams
  validates_uniqueness_of :workstream_code
end
```

error message

```
2.4.0 :026 > Permission.joins(document: {workstream: {id: 1}})
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: 1
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:70:in `walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:67:in `block in walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:65:in `walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:67:in `block in walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:65:in `walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:67:in `block in walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:65:in `walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:62:in `block in walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:61:in `walk_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:52:in `make_tree'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:97:in `initialize'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1071:in `new'
... 9 levels...
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/work/HSDF_DHUB/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/chineduabalogu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why don't you use SQL from the first place to prepare the data, I mean in the action doing something like this `@permissions = Permission.joins(document: {workstream: {id: current_user.workstream.id}})`, then this will will return permissions that belongs to the work sheet of that user, and you can count them with `.count` method, hope it helps.

Comment: it throws an ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError

Comment: Could you update the question with the models argued in the question?
and put the error message too, please.

Comment: thanks for the reply and updated my question

Comment: Try this one, `Permission.joins(document: :workstream).where('workstreams.id = ?', current_user.workstream.id)`, I believe it is going to work, hope it helps.